# How to trigger Oozie jobs on particular condition?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, flume, oozie

I have a folder where all my application log files gets stored. If new log file is created in the folder, immediately my oozie should trigger a Flume job which will put my log file into HDFS.

How to trigger Oozie job when new log file is created in the folder ? 
Any help on this topic is greatly appreciated !!!

Answer (score 1):

That's not how Oozie works. Oozie is a scheduler, a bit like CRON. First, you specify how often a workflow should run and then you can add a requirement for files being available as an additional requirement.

Comment: Thanks jkbkot.. I found something useful here https://github.com/yahoo/oozie/wiki/Oozie-Coord-Use-Cases

Comment: No problem. That's a nice find. It seems better than Oozie documentation.

Comment: be aware that these wiki pages are 2-3 years old

Comment: Oleksii you are right.. I didn't see the date it was posted.. Can anyone help me !!!

Answer (score 0):

I think its more of how you place the files in HDFS. You could always have a parameterized oozie job, which could be invoked using Oozie Java API and passing in the name of the file created on HDFS from the client writing to HDFS itself unless streaming.

Every time a oozie workflow is initiated, it runs on a separate thread and this would allow you to call multiple oozie instances with different parameters.